# In the email subscription of SSRS, the image is not resized

Tags: image, reporting-services

I have a report, which is displayed correctly during normal system usage. The image is resized correctly to fit proportional.

But when I schedule this report, in the mail subscription I received, the image is displayed in an actual size.

I google this issue, found a site( http://www.ssw.com.au/ssw/standards/BetterSoftwareSuggestions/ReportingServices.aspx#ImageSize) saying that the SSRS doesn't support resizing an image in subscription. This site looks quite old. I am not sure it is right or which version it is referring to.

Could you kindly give me an answer?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

SSRS 2008 uses javascript to risize the image.

After I did a couple of tests, I found only outlook didn't display image properly.

Doing some research on Internet, what was found is in outlook 2007 and 2010 Microsoft has disabled their support for javascript for some unknown reasons.

This is the reason that causes my issue. Too bad.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you need to have the images set to FitProportional? If not, try resizing the images  outside of SSRS to be as you want them displayed in the subscription, add them in place of the existing images and set sizing to Original Size (Autosize).

Comment: Yeah. This is what we are doing at the moment. :)